# How did the kind property get removed from (type SquareEvent & type CircleEvent)

Tags: javascript, typescript

how did the kind property get removed from SquareEvent & CircleEvent

```
type EventConfig<Events extends { kind: string }> = { 
  [E in Events as E["kind"]]: (event: E) => void; 
}
type SquareEvent = { kind: "square", x: number, y: number };
type CircleEvent = { kind: "circle", radius: number };
type Config = EventConfig<SquareEvent | CircleEvent> 

//  type Config = {
  square: (event: SquareEvent) => void; 
  circle: (event: CircleEvent) => void; 
}
```

btw u can Find this Example code in the Typescript Handbook page 131

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in Typescript Handbook, right after the snippet you posted:

```
// Remove the 'kind' property
type RemoveKindField<Type> = {
    [Property in keyof Type as Exclude<Property, "kind">]: Type[Property]
};
 
interface Circle {
    kind: "circle";
    radius: number;
}
 
type KindlessCircle = RemoveKindField<Circle>;
           
type KindlessCircle = {
    radius: number;
}
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as

Comment: but  , the snippet after the one i posted had a condition the one i posted  didn't have one